# How do you combine multiple files into 1 using maven assembly?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have tried to combine the two files into 1 common `manifestAB.txt` file. This is a snippet of my `assembly.xml` file.

```
<files>
    <file>
        <source>src/resources/manifestA</source>
        <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
        <destName>manifestAB.txt</destName>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
    <file>
        <source>src/resources/otherDir/manifestB</source>
        <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
        <destName>manifestAB.txt</destName>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
</files>
```

Right now, it is only copying the contents of `manifestA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this approach just like the Maven assembly does: https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/c6ecff9923088d854d4621e17d602f1c70dda806/apache-maven/src/assembly/component.xml#L103-L131